# How to create Redis cluster in DC/OS

Tags: redis, dcos

I was able to create a cluster of Redis instances in my local machine. 
But I was wondering of how we can achieve this in Pass environment i.e. in DC/OS?

Any help will be very helpful.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're specifically looking at DC/OS, you can have a look at the example at https://github.com/dcos/examples/tree/master/redis which covers some of the basic components as you get started.